# Calculating distance from centre of polygon to point using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, point, distance, proximity

How do I calculate the distance between the certain of a polygon (in this case, centre of a district), to the closest point on a map (in this case, the points are road entries)?

I haven't tried anything yet. I know how to find the centre of a polygon, and I know how to calculate distances. But I do not know how to combine the two.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question to tell us what you've tried, and what happens when you try it?  What does or doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use the [Near](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/near.htm) GP tool which:

> Calculates distance and additional proximity information between the
>   input features and the closest feature in another layer or feature
>   class.

If you would like to calculate the distance from the centroid of every polygon (there are many variations on how a centroid could be defined - center of gravity or geometric center), you would need to create first those points (either using [Feature To Point](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/feature-to-point.htm) or other methods such as using [Calculate Geometry](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000009381)).